# What happened to the elderly uniformed toll booth collector?

Tags: the-godfather

1. In *The Godfather* (1972), before [Sonny is Killed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sJU2cz9ytPQ), was that Toll Collector complicit? Was he an authentic Toll Collector who was corrupted? Or did he pretend to be a uniformed Toll Collector?
2. The movie doesn't show the Collector after he drops the cash and ducks. Did he escape the toll booth? If not, what happened to him? Could those sub-machine gun bullets have penetrated the toll booth and killed him too?

[image]

> There's no way the toll collector survived
>
> [3 years ago](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sJU2cz9ytPQ&lc=UgjAE4XnTTmOUXgCoAEC)
>
> [Joe L](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCcippWC9TCWbhJubyAAEmZw) [3 years ago (edited)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sJU2cz9ytPQ&lc=UgjAE4XnTTmOUXgCoAEC.8KAQSXPfgzY8TRENpmIi9H) •
>
> Never thought about that. I never saw him come out of the booth.
>
> [•____• Smith](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC7MFVTDDh1gRuvfvywBbVdw) [2 years ago](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sJU2cz9ytPQ&lc=UgjAE4XnTTmOUXgCoAEC.8KAQSXPfgzY8dOLp_6kili) •
>
> I think he was in on it though. He purposely dropped the coin so he could duck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### He survived

It's clearly stated in the base novel that the *bogus* collector survived and was in on the assassinaton.

> Seconds afterward, all four men, the three actual assassins and the **bogus toll collector**, were in their car and speeding toward the Meadowbrook Parkway on the other side of Jones Beach.
>
> <sup>*The Godfather* - Mario Puzo</sup>

Comment: I thought to ask this question about a week ago.  I'm not so sure it's a given he is with the gunmen.  The toll booth is riddled with holes; there's no way he would have survived.  And as far as being true to the book, there were many, many gunmen in the movie.  The collector's ducking action could very well have been a reaction to seeing the gunmen appear from their hiding, brandishing weapons.

Comment: If you look again you can see that it's only the top section of the booth that is shot up. The collector is on the floor where it was safe. It's extremely unlikely that any rounds would have gone right through Sonny's car to hit the collector. Regardless who are you going to believe if not the guy who wrote the book and the movie?

Comment: Point ceded............